# Generate one-time key with AES in Counter mode

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, jce

How to generate one-time key in AES counter mode using java cryptography? I want to use that one-time key as session key in my PGP implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key generation is not dependent on the cipher mode. To generate the key, use a `KeyGenerator`.

```
KeyGenerator aes = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
aes.init(128);
SecretKey secret = aes.generateKey();
```